# Issues with devtools/installing packages

Tags: r, devtools

I am in having issues installing packages on R. when i trying to run `install.packages("devtools")` i am receiving the following message

> install.packages("devtools")
>   --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
>   also installing the dependencies ‘zeallot’, ‘colorspace’, ‘utf8’, ‘vctrs’, ‘plyr’, ‘farver’, ‘labeling’, ‘munsell’, ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘pillar’, ‘pkgconfig’, ‘httpuv’, ‘xtable’, ‘sourcetools’, ‘fastmap’, ‘gtable’, ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’, ‘tibble’, ‘viridisLite’, ‘BH’, ‘sys’, ‘ini’, ‘backports’, ‘ps’, ‘lazyeval’, ‘shiny’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘later’, ‘askpass’, ‘clipr’, ‘clisymbols’, ‘curl’, ‘fs’, ‘gh’, ‘purrr’, ‘rprojroot’, ‘whisker’, ‘yaml’, ‘processx’, ‘R6’, ‘assertthat’, ‘fansi’, ‘rex’, ‘htmltools’, ‘htmlwidgets’, ‘magrittr’, ‘crosstalk’, ‘promises’, ‘mime’, ‘openssl’, ‘prettyunits’, ‘xopen’, ‘brew’, ‘commonmark’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘stringi’, ‘stringr’, ‘xml2’, ‘evaluate’, ‘praise’, ‘usethis’, ‘callr’, ‘cli’, ‘covr’, ‘crayon’, ‘desc’, ‘digest’, ‘DT’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘glue’, ‘git2r’, ‘httr’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘memoise’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘pkgload’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘remotes’, ‘rlang’, ‘roxygen2’, ‘rstudioapi’, ‘rversions’, ‘sessioninfo’, ‘testthat’, ‘withr’

trying URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/zeallot_0.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 62200 bytes (60 KB)
downloaded 60 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/colorspace_1.4-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2550276 bytes (2.4 MB)
downloaded 2.4 MB

[image]

Comment: The output indicates that the installation is working. Just be patient as the long list of packages is being processed.

Comment: You missed. "Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session". R asks you to supply more information.  One way to do so would be to use `install.packages("devtools", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")`

Comment: It looks done. Check for example that the package RColorBrewer was installed successfully: library(RColorBrewer); display.brewer.all()

Comment: @Ryan Walsh: just a suggestion use RStudio instead of native R GUI. It's so much better https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download